# AJAX - Post to MVC Controller method without reloading page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I created an MVC View page where, when a user clicks a button, a Controller method is called.  The method returns a text expression.  This expression is then displayed in a pop-up message.

The pop-up functionality works when the button is clicked, however, it has an unwanted side effect of causing the page to reload. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is the HTML which renders the button:

```html
<button id="btnListGroups" title="List the groups the selected service ID is a member of">List Groups</button>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnListGroups").click(function () {
        var val = $("#ddlServiceID").val();
        $.post("/Home/GetGroups", { serviceID: val }, function (data, textStatus) 
        {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
})
```

And finally, here is the Controller method:

```
public partial class HomeController : Controller
{
    public MvcHtmlString GetGroups(string serviceID)
    {
        ADHandler adHandler = new ADHandler();

        string groups = adHandler.GetGroupMemberships(serviceID);
        return new MvcHtmlString(groups);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening from a basic button click unless it is connected to a form. Did you try adding event.preventDefault(); to the js function?

Comment: is your button inside a form ? use `preventDefault`

Comment: @SeanLeroy - Thanks!  Yes, the button exists within a form block.  adding event.preventDefault(); to the .click function resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to install query.unobtrusive-ajax  package from nuget manager in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page reload was occurring because the button exists within an HTML Form.  By default, the "type" attribute of HTML buttons is "submit" unless otherwise specified.  Since I hadn't specified a "type" for my button, clicking the button was being interpreted as as a form submit.

To resolve this, I set the type attribute for my button as "button"

```html
<button type="button" id="btnListGroups" title="List the groups the selected service ID is a member of">List Groups</button>
```

Comment: Also, `<button />` default value for "type" is submit; if you define a button as `<button type="button" .. />` it also won't postback.

Comment: @MikeBruno +1 to Brian's solution as it is a bit cleaner in my opinion